# Prevent TLS/SSL Birthday attacks on 64-bit block ciphers (SWEET32)

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, vulnerabilities

Our recent VA report shows that there are TLS/SSL Birthday attacks on 64-bit block ciphers possible on Kubernetes `etcd` ports.

Suggested solution is **Configure the server to disable support for 3DES suite.**

Our problems are :

- How to disable support for 3DES suite?
- How this configuration will affect to our running Kubernetes services?
- How to Configure the server to disable support for static key cipher suites?

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#limiting-access-of-etcd-clusters) suggest a way to access only API server to access, but I dont understand how to apply it for running kubernetes instance.

Any help, suggestions will be greatly appreciated.Also note, I am not an expert net admin.

Answer (score 2):

The cipher suites can be set via [cipher-suites parameter](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4.0/op-guide/security/):

```
$ etcd \
  --cipher-suites TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

According to [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.2.0/installing/tls.html) those cipher suites should be secure.

Edit :

For fixing this in running `etcd` in Kubernetes on Ubuntu-18.04 LTE.

edit : `/etc/etcd.env` add this line :

`ETCD_CIPHER_SUITES=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/etcd1" is already in use by container "9f4c86.....". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Comment: That means that an etcd container is already running. You need to add that parameter to the service/start script/k8s deployment which manages your etcd cluster. It depends on your specific setup.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, where is these scripts are located?
I have Ubuntu 18.04 servers with Kubernetes v1.18.5

Comment: Sorry, as said that depends on your setup. I usually worked with managed k8s clusters. Maybe it was setup like this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/setup-ha-etcd-with-kubeadm/

Comment: Yes, its not your fault. I added that part to make it easy for someone. Here we have baremetal servers. Its really hard to find solutions and also we are newbies for kubernetes.